# Dropbox throws "Invalid redirect_uri" error, although exactly the same url is specified in the app

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox, datastore, redirect

I want to start my Dropbox-app by linking to a dropbox account as specified here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/js

However, dropbox won't redirect back to my website and throws "Invalid redirect_uri"
I specified various redirect urls and double checked my app_key, but i could not get it to work. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When I had this issue, I realized that when refreshing the dropbox app console page, it hadn't saved my domain value. Apparently, ONLY HTTPS prefixed domains will work. When I added https it worked fine and saved my value, then I was able to get that to work with my javascript, but I was wishing that I didn't have to setup a server with a cert just to test. Security security, I guess.

```
http://blah.com     // didn't work
https://blah.com    // did work
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the full, exact URL is registered as a redirect URI. (E.g. `https://www.mydomain.com/mypage.html`) The error message in the browser should tell you the exact URI that was attempted, so you should be able to match it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am brand new on this and ran into the same issue today attempting to follow the "Dropbox Datastores and Drop-Ins" tutorial on net.tutsplus.com

My setup is on a local system as well with the solution in a sub directory called "todo".

By trial and error, I got through to the authorisation screen by adding this URI in the Dropbox Developer Console: "http://LH.LH/todo/" (without quotes, AND because of comment restrictions on this board, please replace "LH.LH" with "localhost")

Btw I can see in the console, that there are some other issues with the code, but I will be looking into that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the same issue. It works fine locally, but not on production. I find it to be because of the redirection URI: it adds the 'http://' bit, while you can't add this to the list of supported URI in the Dropbox app list.

Try changing the url manually from the browser, removing the http:// and leaving only the domain. Does it work? If so, you have the same problem as I do... which I still don't know how to fix :(

Comment: This isn't true. In fact, you should always specify `https://` (or possibly `http://` for localhost or 127.0.0.1 URLs). Make sure you're adding this in the right place... you should be adding an OAuth 2 redirect URI.